# Swing Overlapping components

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have two AWT components in a Frame, Panel A and Panel B. I would like panel A to be sized to the height width of the frame (and maintain that size on frame resize), but I would like panel B to overlap A. B will be at a fixed position (0,0 to make it easier) with a fixed height and width. I'm not sure what kind of layout manager I would need to make this work. If I use a null layout, I think I would have to manage the resizing of panel A myself, but it would make the sizing of panel B relatively easy. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: You said that panel A's width should match the frame's width- what about its height?

Comment: Yes, basically I want A to fill the entire Frame, both height and width.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [`JLayeredPane`s](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html).  [Here is a tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html).

edit:

If panelA is an AWT component, you will be hard pressed to get panelB to overlap.   From Sun's article entitled [Mixing Heavy and Light Components](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/):

> Do not mix lightweight (Swing) and heavyweight (AWT) components within  a container where the lightweight component is expected to overlap the  heavyweight one.

However, if you are looking to have panelA fill the Frame completely, why not add panelB as a component of panelA?

Edit2:

If you can make panelB a heavyweight component, then you can use the `JLayeredPane`.

Here is a quick mockup that shows how:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    new GUITest();
}

public GUITest() {
    frame = new JFrame("test");
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    addStuffToFrame();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}       

private void addStuffToFrame() {    
    Panel awtPanel = new Panel();
    awtPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    //here you can fool around with the pane:
    //first, you can see how the layered pane works by switching the 
    //DEFUALT_LAYER and PALLETTE_LAYER back and forth between the two panels
    //and re-compiling to see the results
    awtPanel.setSize(200,300);
    frame.getLayeredPane().add(awtPanel, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    //next you comment out the above two lines and 
    //uncomment the following line. this will give you the desired effect of
    //awtPanel filling in the entire frame, even on a resize. 
    //frame.add(awtPanel);

    Panel awtPanel2 = new Panel();
    awtPanel2.setBackground(Color.red);
    awtPanel2.setSize(300,200);
    frame.getLayeredPane().add(awtPanel2,JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER);
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that JPanel A is actually an AWT component, my mistake. I'll edit the post.

Comment: I can make B AWT as well, no problems there. The issue is the PanelA (which I don't have control over) is not a Container, so it doesn't have the add methods. I want to just add them both to some parent container, but that's where I'm not sure about how to lay them out properly so A fills the entire container, but B just fills a portion of it.

Comment: Sorry, got away from this for a little while. I'll check this out in a little while and upvote/accept if it works. Thanks!

Comment: It didn't really occur to me to use JLayeredPane with AWT components, but this works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to have your own LayoutManager. The easiest way is probably to extend or proxy BorderLayout, and have a specific case to layout panel B.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something. If B is fixed size and is at (0,0) and A runs the full width what's the use of having B overlap A? You will never see anything that is placed under B.

I can't think of any of the default layout managers, but Orielly has this one you can use:
[relative layout manager](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/09/18/relativelayout.html) (see source code link) with [documentation](http://onjava.com/onjava/2002/09/18/doc/com/brunchboy/util/swing/relativelayout/package-summary.html). I haven't used it in a long while, but it should beat managing the layout yourself.

Comment: Eventually I will make B not fixed such that it can move to different locations. In the first pass, I'm just keeping it at 0,0. You are correct though, I won't see that piece that B covers, but that is ok. Screen real estate is at a premium and B is small, so I'd rather cover up a small section of A than use something like BorderLayout and waste a large part of the screen I won't use.