# Cannot mix lightweight and heavyweight components in an undecorated JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am attempting to mix heavyweight and lightweight components according to [these](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html) guidelines.

I am expecting the following code to paint the entire window green. Instead, it renders half the screen red:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Testcase extends Canvas
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

  public static void main(String[] arg)
  {
    final boolean enableWorkaround = false;
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JLayeredPane layers = new JLayeredPane();
        frame.getContentPane().add(layers);

        JPanel green = new JPanel();
        green.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        green.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);
        layers.add(green, Integer.valueOf(1));

        Canvas red = new Canvas();
        red.setBackground(Color.RED);
        red.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 600);
        layers.add(red, Integer.valueOf(0));

        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        if (!enableWorkaround)
          frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Reproduced on:

```
java version "1.6.0_23"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_23-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and

```
java version "1.7.0-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-ea-b124)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.0-b05, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Does my code contain any bugs or is this a legitimate JDK bug?

Comment: Basic question: Why do you need to mix light and heavy weigh components?  Last I read was that SUN said this was not a good idea (or course that was a while ago).  What happens when you just use swing without mixing in AWT components?

Comment: We can't go purely lightweight because Java 3D engines all use OpenGL native canvases under the hood. We can't go purely heavyweight because the legacy part of our application is based on Swing and there is little incentive to rewrite it (we don't need 3D for those components).

Comment: Have you read this ? http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/

Comment: Yes, the article I linked to is newer than yours.

Comment: [Working link to Oracle article about mixing AWT and SWING](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Oracle, this is a known limitation that will be fixed in the future: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7012806

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be fine, since it works as you'd think if you used a JPanel instead of a Canvas for `red` .This appears to be a bug in mixing heavyweight and lightweight components.

As mentioned in the selected answer for [this question on overlapping components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428193/swing-overlapping-components), it seems that it's still a bad idea to mix heavyweight and lightweight components if it involves overlapping a **lightweight** component over a **heavyweight** component.

However, overlapping a **heavyweight** over a **lightweight** component does seem to work, so if you change `green` into the Canvas and `red` into the JPanel, it will work. It will also work if both are JPanels or both are Canvases.

That said, unless you really need to, it's generally better to avoid mixing lightweight and heavyweight components.

Hope that helps.