# JAVA: awt on swing component displaying problem

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I am using java to design a GUI; I inserted a java.awt.List on a JPanel component. My program works correctly but as showing this panel I see delay and displacement problem in showing List component. I can use javax.swing.JList (Swing component) on Jpanel and result is OK. Is there a constant problem in using awt components on swing components? Can I solve it to use java.awt.List on my JPanel?

thank you all....
sajad

Comment: *Why* do you want to mix Swing & AWT components?

Comment: If you start with Swing, stick with Swing. Everything will be much easier.

Comment: yes I know using swing and JList is better; but I just want to know cause of this problem and also solution if possible.

Comment: can you post some sample code? Generally was not a very good idea to mix swing and AWT (http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/), but from JDK 6 update 17, this could be easier to accomplish. See http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/mixing_components/index.html

Comment: the solution is to use Swing components on a JPanel

Answer (score 3):

nobody know how your code works, you have to show us for better/valuable answer for your problem(s), but there still not good idea [Mixing heavy and light components](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/) or [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/mixing_components/) maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695833/cannot-mix-lightweight-and-heavyweight-components-in-an-undecorated-jframe) can help you

EDIT: bacis tutorial about [JPanel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) with [JList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) layed by some of [LayoutManagers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), examples for that on [Java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm) inc. [Layout](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Layout.htm)

Comment: I just added List on Jpanel in netbeans IDEA and the code auto generated such as: .addComponent(playList1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 159, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))......... but I see this page to see there is any point for my problem. thank you

Comment: @sajad I don't know something about Netbans' GroupLayout, but there are exist lots of ways how to solve that by using Swing, please see my edit