# OpenGL canvas if flickering in JFrame on a Windows platform

Tags: windows, swing, kotlin, opengl

This question has a "kotlin" label only because it's code is in kotlin, there's nothing kotlin-specific in this example, equivalent java code fails exactly the same way.

Running following code (I've created a repo with this minimal example: https://github.com/shabunc/issues-opengl-flickering):

```kotlin
private fun createGlPanel(): GLCanvas {
    val profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2)
    val capabilities = GLCapabilities(profile)
    capabilities.sampleBuffers = true
    capabilities.doubleBuffered = true
    return GLCanvas(capabilities)
}

private class SwingFrame : JFrame() {

    val canvas = createGlPanel()

    init {
        addWindowListener(object : WindowAdapter() {
            override fun windowClosing(evt: WindowEvent) {
                dispose()
                exitProcess(0)
            }
        })
        contentPane.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER)
        setSize(600, 500)
        isVisible = false
    }
}

fun initApp() {
    val frame = SwingFrame()
    val canvas = frame.canvas

    canvas.addGLEventListener(object : GLEventListener {
        override fun reshape(glautodrawable: GLAutoDrawable, x: Int, y: Int, width: Int, height: Int) {
        }

        override fun init(glautodrawable: GLAutoDrawable) {
            glautodrawable.gl.gL2.glClearColor(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f)
            val animator = FPSAnimator(glautodrawable, 60, false)
            animator.start()
        }

        override fun dispose(glautodrawable: GLAutoDrawable) {}
        override fun display(glautodrawable: GLAutoDrawable) {}
    })

    frame.isVisible = true
}

fun main() {
    val frame = initApp()
}
```

supposed to launch a window with a red background on it, which is what exactly happens on Linux and MacOS. On windows, though, I got crazy flickering and having hard times to understand how can I change this code to fix this. I would appreciate any hints because hacks like `-Dsun.awt.noerasebackground=true` (this is only thing I managed to google) ain't working for me as well. I really hope I'm missing something elementary because it's almost "Hello world" level of example.

Comment: My guess is that you are mixing heavyweight and lightweight components. Refer to [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/mixing-components.html) and [Heavyweight/Lightweight Components Mix](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/awt010.html) and this SO question: [Cannot mix lightweight and heavyweight components in an undecorated JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695833/cannot-mix-lightweight-and-heavyweight-components-in-an-undecorated-jframe)

Comment: Also not sure have you tried the office demo of using JOGL in swing https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Using_JOGL_in_AWT_SWT_and_Swing#JOGL_in_Swing

Answer (score 0):

After investigating some other examples the minimal difference between mine code and code that doesn't flicker was [following](https://github.com/shabunc/issues-opengl-flickering/commit/8a32abde295cd5f716ce43e779f84a1c7a27f2d6):

```kotlin
  override fun display(glautodrawable: GLAutoDrawable) {
            glautodrawable.gl.gL2.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        }
```