# Swing JLayeredPane not painting all elements on paintAll call

Tags: java, swing, canvas, awt, jlayeredpane

I have `JLayeredPane` that contains `Canvas` on level 0(fills itself yellow color in `Paint` method) and `JPanel` on level 1(set's it background as red in constructor).

On button click in `paintAllToImage` method I create `BufferedImage` and draw `JLayerePane` on this image using `component.paintAll(image.getGraphics());` 
 The problem is, that image has only `Canvas` painted (it is completely filled in yellow). Please see image attached.

[image]

(part above button is what is actually drawn, part below button is image, created from `JLayeredPane`)

Here is the full code:

```
public class LayeredPaneEx extends JPanel {

    private JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    public LayeredPaneEx()    {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 310));
        layeredPane.setLayout(null);

        Canvas panel = new CustomCanvas();
        panel.setSize(300, 400);
        CustomPanel customPanel = new CustomPanel();
        layeredPane.add(panel, new Integer(0));
        layeredPane.add(customPanel, new Integer(1));

        add(layeredPane);

        JButton paintBtn = new JButton("Paint All");
        paintBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(paintAllToImage(layeredPane));
                JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(icon);
                add(imageLabel);
            }
        });
        add(paintBtn);

        JLabel paintLabel = new JLabel();
        paintLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    }

    private class CustomCanvas extends Canvas  {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }

    private class CustomPanel extends JPanel {
        CustomPanel() {
            setSize(100, 100);
            setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("LayeredPaneDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JComponent newContentPane = new LayeredPaneEx();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static BufferedImage paintAllToImage(Component component) {
        BufferedImage image;
        image = new BufferedImage(
                component.getWidth(),
                component.getHeight(),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
        );
        component.paintAll(image.getGraphics());
        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware of mixing heavy weight (`Canvas`) with light weight components. Because AWT components don't have a concept of z-ordering, you will find that this will cause you no end of issues. Also, you should prefer `printAll` over `paintAll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: new answer**

By adapting this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1428298/1694043), it seems to be possible to put a lightweight `CustomPanel` in a heavyweight `Panel` and put those on top of another heavyweight `Panel`. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot showing lightweight on top of heavyweight]

And here is the program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1428298/1694043.
 */
public class GuiTest {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        new GuiTest();
    }

    public GuiTest() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Heavyweight versus lightweight");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addPanelsToFrame(frame);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> frame.setVisible(true));
    }

    private void addPanelsToFrame(JFrame frame) {
        CustomCanvas customCanvas = new CustomCanvas(300, 400, Color.YELLOW);
        Panel awtPanel1 = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
        awtPanel1.setSize(300, 400);
        awtPanel1.add(customCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getLayeredPane().add(awtPanel1, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

        CustomPanel customPanel = new CustomPanel(100, 100, Color.RED);
        Panel awtPanel2 = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
        awtPanel2.setSize(100, 100);
        awtPanel2.add(customPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getLayeredPane().add(awtPanel2, JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER);
    }


    private class CustomCanvas extends Canvas {
        private Color backgroundColor;

        public CustomCanvas(int width, int height, Color backgroundColor) {
            setSize(width, height);
            this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(backgroundColor);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }


    private class CustomPanel extends JPanel {
        public CustomPanel(int width, int height, Color backgroundColor) {
            setSize(width, height);
            setBackground(backgroundColor);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Old answer**

Using the advice of [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) to avoid the `Canvas` class, you could use two instances of your `CustomPanel` class. This class extends the Swing based lightweight `JPanel` instead of the heavyweight AWT based `Canvas`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13769255/1694043 for more information on lightweight versus heavyweight Java GUI components.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of modified program]

Here is the modified code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LayeredPaneEx extends JPanel {
    private JLayeredPane layeredPane;

    public LayeredPaneEx()    {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 310));
        layeredPane.setLayout(null);

        //Canvas panel = new CustomCanvas();
        //panel.setSize(300, 400);
        //CustomPanel customPanel = new CustomPanel();
        //layeredPane.add(panel, new Integer(0));
        //layeredPane.add(customPanel, new Integer(1));
        layeredPane.add(new CustomPanel(300, 400, Color.YELLOW), new Integer(0));
        layeredPane.add(new CustomPanel(100, 100, Color.RED), new Integer(1));

        add(layeredPane);

        JButton paintBtn = new JButton("Paint All");
        paintBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(paintAllToImage(layeredPane));
                JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(icon);
                add(imageLabel);
            }
        });
        add(paintBtn);

        JLabel paintLabel = new JLabel();
        paintLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    }

//    private class CustomCanvas extends Canvas  {
//        @Override
//        public void paint(Graphics g) {
//            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
//            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
//        }
//    }

    private class CustomPanel extends JPanel {
        public CustomPanel(int width, int height, Color backgroundColor) {
            setSize(width, height);
            setBackground(backgroundColor);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("LayeredPaneDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JComponent newContentPane = new LayeredPaneEx();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public BufferedImage paintAllToImage(Component component) {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
                component.getWidth(),
                component.getHeight(),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
        );
        component.paintAll(image.getGraphics());

        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that would definitely work, but what if I have to draw my JPanel on top of Canvas? As "Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components" Oracle article says, there should be no problem on Java 8 (wich I'm using). Although in this situation Canvas is drawn on top of JPanel.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use two lightweight panels. Then it should not matter which panel is on top. As I see it, there is no reason to use a heavyweight component in this program. If you want to draw, you can override the `paintComponent` method of the panel.

Comment: A nice tutorial on custom painting in Swing: [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: Sadly, this program is just a sandbox version of real task, that has overlapping `Canvas` and `JPanel` in one `Container`.

Comment: I understand, you have a legacy situation. How difficult would it be to replace the `Canvas` component with a `JPanel`?

Comment: Replacing is not an option. I could probably try to wrap `Canvas` in `JPanel` so panel will draw canvas on `paint()`, and pass all events to canvas. Though I still hope for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Could you use the `paintAllToImage` method on the `Canvas` component and add that image to a panel in the `JLayeredPane`? This way, you have the heavyweight component as an image in the lightweight components.